# display pandas DataFrame evolution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, boids

I had fun encoding BOIDS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boids in python and now I have a DataFrame with each line representing a bird, and its associated coordinates (x and y).

So for every second, I have the coordinate of every point.

I would like to display my birds trips on a graph that evolves through time.

Do you have any technology compatible with pandas that I could use to see my birds flight ?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/animation_api.html

Comment: thanks, I'm also investigating animplot from hhpy